# google app script problem with add spreadsheet data to tbody rows

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, web-applications

hi guys im struggling to acccomplished this. ive created web app script in google apps script. what i want to do is when i submit my form i will get spreadsheet data to my table > tbody as rows in my index.html file
ps: im using jquery 
Thanks btw

## code.gs

```
function getTableRows(sheetname){

   if(sheetname){
      var mysheet = sheetname
   }else{
      var mysheet = 'my sheet name'
   }

   var tableRows = [];
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myspreadsheetID').getSheetByName(mysheet);
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
   var theRange = sheet.getDataRange()
   var Rangedata = theRange.getValues()

   for (var i=1; i < Rangedata.length; i++){
      tableRows.push(Rangedata[i])
   }

   return tableRows
}
```

## javascript.js

```
function loadTableData(data){

    var tableRow = $('#tableSheet tbody');
    var markup = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {       
       markup += "<tr>";
       for(var j=0; j < data[i].length; j++){
          markup += "<td>" + data[i][j] + "</td>";              
       }
       markup += "</tr>";
    }

    tableRow.html(markup);
 }

function onFormSubmit(){

    var selectedSheet = $('#sheetSelector option:selected').text();
    alert(selectedSheet)
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(loadTableData)
    .withFailureHandler(showError)
    .getTableRows(selectedSheet) 
}

index.html
===========
<form id="frmSheetQuery" name="frmSheetQuery" method="GET" action="<?= pubUrl ?>" class="form-inline" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">...</form>

<table id="tableSheet" class="table">
     <thead>
      <tr id="tableRowHeader">
         <th scope="col">... header row goes here</th>
         ...
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableRows">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add more information like what errors did you encounter or if there is any?